# Google Maps Javascript API additional zoom / scale image

Tags: google-maps-api-3

I know that Google Maps has maximum allowed zoom for every location on all map types. On most places, using the Satellite map type, the maximum zoom level is about 20-21. **Is there a way to disable that limit, so that if I try to set the zoom at a higher level than "maximum zoom" (e.g. 25), the images get scaled (stretched)?**

Answer (score 1):

In Google Maps api v3, the map shows image files (aka map tiles) for each zoom levels.
It means all map tiles are drew in Google server, then distribute to your browser.
For that reason, even if you set higher level than the maximum zoom level, the map images are not scaled.